# Manga where a guy grows a rare plant, lives with demi humans and dryads(?), and has rare crystals

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I read this during quarantine and I can't find it anymore but I remember it had about 20 chapters.

Basically the start of this story was that he was some noble child (either kicked out or given a land since he's not the successor) and his family gave him this "Healing berry plant" thingy. It appears to be a rare and expensive plant and he has powers to grow lots of plants.

One day a group of demi humans (cats, specifically, that always say "nya" at the very end of everything they say) found him in the forest during their travels (they're merchants) and they asked if they could buy the berries. He agreed and the cats sold the berries and basically asked him if they could live with him and again he agreed. He made tree houses from scratch for about 30 cats and they lived together.

After that, they found a statue on the tree which was actually a powerful dryad (like people looking, but they're trees). He saves this person and the dryad also decided to live there. They have huge flowers on top of their heads and they like being buried in the soil while getting watered (like plants).

This was sort of in the last chapter that I've read but he found like these fluffy chicks and took one in. He also saved a girl who was a legendary hero or something and the baby chick (who's also very powerful) calls them mama and papa.

The last time I read this was that they updated and they had a chapter where it's like a full-fledged village and they also took in some mercenaries and soldiers that now live in the village.

Comment: Just to confirm, are "fluffy chicks" women or, you know, chickens? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Start a Leisurely Lord Life With a Plant Magic Cheat After Farming With the Knowledge of the Previous Life, a Reversal Life Began](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/hzetwv3/shokubutsu-mahou-chito-de-nonbiri-ryoshu-seikatsu-hajimemasu-zense-no-chishiki-o-kushi-shite-nogyo-shitara-gyakuten-jinsei-hajimatta-kudan)***...?

> Elt, who reincarnated in an MMORPG as an aristocrat, was branded as incompetent and was thrown out as a manager of a remote area with zero territories.
>
> However, his "plant magic" was the best all-purpose magic for territorial development! As he cultivated by utilizing the magic that produces from crops to buildings and the knowledge of the previous life, the territory increased and became lively.

The main character is reincarnated as Elt Nagasch, the fourth son of a duke in the world of an MMORPG he used to play. His family doesn't value him though, because the magic attribute he was born with is plant magic, which isn't looked upon as favourably as combat-oriented magic.

At the age of 15, he's thrown out of his house, appointed as the feudal lord of a neglected territory, and told not to come back until he's made it flourish. One of the first things he does when he gets there is grow magical plants with berries that can be used as the ingredients for healing potions.

After living there for two weeks, some merchant cat people (who say "nya" at the end of every sentence) arrive and ask Elt for permission to pass through his territory. He grants it, and offers to sell them some of his berries, which he now has a large stockpile of. The cat people consider these berries to be very rare and valuable, and ask if they can set up a base on Elt's land. He grants it, and grows them some treehouses to live in.

A bit later, a wooden statue of a girl is discovered lodged between the roots of one of the treehouses Elt grew, and when he uses his magic on it, the statue comes to life and introduces herself as Stella Narestar. The cat people recognise her as a hero and an S-ranked adventurer.

Later still, Elt meets some dryads with flowers on top of their heads, who end up coming to live in the village he's now establishing. The dryads enjoy being buried neck-deep in the ground.

After that, Elt and Stella encounter some cute, fluffy bird-like monsters called cockatrices. Stella brings a cockatrice egg back to the village, and when it hatches, the baby cockatrice refers to Stella and Elt as mother and father.

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH   

Comment: @Kyla_banana - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].